# CMake, Public private folder structure

Tags: c++, cmake, directory-structure

If I have a folder-structure like this:

```
.
├── Core
│   ├── Private
│   │   └── example.cpp
│   └── Public
│       └── example.h
└── Math
    ├── Private
    │   └── Math.cpp
    └── Public
        └── Math.h
```

How would I accomplish it, in CMake, to make a import, in example the folder Math/Private, like this:

```
#include <Core/example.h>
```

Of course **example.h** is the header file from **example.cpp**. Even there, how would I link them without writing:

```
#include <../Public/example.h>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot accompilish this with the given project structure: There simply is no `example.h` file with a parent directory `Core`.

Restructure the project and use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

**Project structure**

```
.
├── Core
│   ├── Private
│   │   └── example.cpp
│   └── include
│       └── Core
│           └── example.h
├── Math
│   ├── Private
│   │   └── Math.cpp
│   └── include
│       └── Math
│           └── Math.h
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CORE_SRC
    Private/example.cpp
    include/Core/example.h
)

list(TRANSFORM CORE_SRC PREPEND Core/)

set(MATH_SRC
    Private/Math.cpp
    include/Math/Math.h
)

list(TRANSFORM MATH_SRC PREPEND Math/)

add_executable(my_program
    ${CORE_SRC}
    ${MATH_SRC}
)

target_include_directories(my_program PRIVATE
    Math/include
    Core/include
)
```

**Note:** If you want to create separate targets for the components `Math` and `Core`, you could use `PUBLIC` instead of `PRIVATE` for the visibility of the include directories which would result in any cmake targets linking your cmake library targets to automatically gain access to those include directories without the need to repeat this kind of in multiple places.